# C++ code skips over if statement. Doesn't allow user to give input

Tags: c++

new to C++ programming. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my following code? The problem right now is that the if statement is ignoring any value you give it, and just goes to the section of code within the if statement.

There's also a problem with the code within the if statement itself. It doesn't take any input from the user. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 80
#include <iostream>
int main(void)
{
  FILE * pFile;
  int c; // variable to hold character input by user
  char sentence[SIZE]; // create char array
  int i = 0; // initialize counter i
  int number;
  std::cout << "Give a number. 1 for file. Anything else for standard.";
  std::cin >> number;
  std::cin.clear();

  if(number=1)
  {
   printf("Enter sentence to append: ");
   fgets(sentence,256,stdin);
    pFile=fopen("mylog.txt","a");
    fputs(sentence,pFile);
    fclose(pFile);
  }
 else
 {

   // prompt user to enter line of text
   puts("Enter a line of text:");

   // use getchar to read each character
   while ((i < SIZE-1) && (c = getchar()) != '\n') {
   sentence[i++] = c;}

   sentence[i]= '\0';

   // terminate string
   // use puts to display sentence

   puts("\nThe line entered was:");
   puts(sentence);
 }


 }
```

Comment: `if(number=1)` => `if(number==1)`.

Comment: And the line after the `while` loop will write out of bounds if the user types in more than 80 characters, and the `fgets()` may also read up to 256 characters into the same 80 character array.

Comment: Alright, fixed those, but it still won't take input from the user though. It displays "Enter sentence to append", but then skips right to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` is an assignment operator. You are just setting the value of `number` to `1`. The `==` operator will compare the two values.

Comment: Fixed that already. Any idea as to why the rest of it isn't working?

Comment: You may want to check out this reference for fgets http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/